# Correct way to reference content in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, relative-path

When running my web app on my local machine i can ref css/scripts/images using:

```
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But when I deployed to my Development server, it wasn't able to find any of my content. After researching the issue everyone suggests using the below method:

```
<link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<img src="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/3.png")%>" />
```

At least now all my content is loaded and works when I push to the development server.  However now that I have the server script in there, the "Design" view in Visual Studio doesn't load any styling/etc. I'm wondering if there is an alternative or something I'm missing that perhaps would fix this? Or maybe I'm going about it all wrong? Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, I figured the Designer is just a waste of time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggestion you found is a great way to reference content.

As far as Design View goes, don't sacrifice the elegance of your code just to get Design View.  Learn to love Code View.  Preview in a browser.  In my experience, that workflow really has no major downsides (once you get used to it).

(As an aside, I think most of the developers who like ASP.NET MVC do not use "Design View" in Visual Studio.  One of the reasons I love MVC is that it allows me to be picky about the markup.  Any kind of designer lies outside that kind of thinking.)

Comment: Agreed.  I never use the Design View in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I never use Design View period.

Answer (score 4):

You can always cheat the designer with an atrocity similar to this:

```
<% if (false) { %>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } %>
<link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but hey, quite honestly hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> in the browser will give you faster results than waiting for the designer to load (even if your application is hosted on the other end of the world).

Comment: That's a high price to pay for design view.  Browser refresh is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Larsenal, completely agree. While in the classic WebForms world, a designer could be useful, in the ASP.NET MVC world there's no sane justification for its usage.

Answer (score 1):

Design view is broken?  Thats not a bug in your code, thats just the way it is.  This is true for ASP.NET MVC and regular ASP.NET